# How do I change colors in the Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, solution-explorer

How do I change the background text and other colors in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio (IDE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control Panel - Display Properties - Appearance

The solution explorer can't be configured like the text editor.

Comment: solution explorer can be changed too: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76b86cc7-7838-4b12-bbb9-a69985b663ed?SRC=Home

Comment: A downvote after 2 years? Wow, this place is really turning into a dump.